# How to solve Python TypeError?

Tags: python, psycopg2, typeerror

This is my code below and I try to load data from one database to another. I believe everything works fine but an error occurs and I don't know what this means.

```
import pymssql, psycopg2

class Datenbankabfrage:

def __init__(self):
    self.conn1 = pymssql.connect(host='***', user='***', password='***', database='****')
    self.conn2 = psycopg2.connect("dbname='****' user='****' host='****' password='****'")

    self.cur1 = self.conn1.cursor()
    self.cur2 = self.conn2.cursor()

def abfrage(self):
    self.cur1.execute("SELECT tag, site, plant, unit, line, ProcessID AS pid, Count(ReadTime) AS mods \
                        FROM ( \
                        select dateadd(dd, -1, convert(varchar, getDate(),111)) \
                        as tag, ReadTime, processID, subid, PR.Site, PR.Plant, PR.Unit, PR.Line \
                        from FactBarcodeReading BCR with(nolock) \
                        inner join DimProcess PR on BCR.ProcessKey = PR.ProcessKey \
                        where PR.ProcessID IN  (802, 1190, 1800, 3090, 3590, 4390, 4590, 4800, 5000, 5400, 4190) \
                        and ReadTime between dateadd(dd, -1, convert(varchar, getDate(),111)) \
                        and dateadd(dd, -0, convert(varchar, getDate(),111)) \
                        ) a \
                        GROUP BY tag, site, plant, unit, line, ProcessID \
                        ORDER BY site, plant, unit, line, ProcessID")

    self.rows = self.cur1.fetchall()

    query = ("INSERT INTO '20091229global' (proddate, site, plant, unit, line, pid, mods) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", self.rows)

    self.cur2.executemany(query)

    self.conn2.commit()

    self.conn2.close()



a = Datenbankabfrage()
a.abfrage()
```

This is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Documents and Settings\FS107319\My Documents\Python\mssql_abfrage.py", line 39, in <module>
a.abfrage()
File "C:\Documents and Settings\FS107319\My Documents\Python\mssql_abfrage.py", line 30, in    abfrage
self.cur2.executemany(query)
TypeError: Required argument 'vars_list' (pos 2) not found
```

## ------------------------------------------------------------------------

Ok here is my edit:

Now, this is my new code

```
query("INSERT INTO '20091229global' (proddate, site, plant, unit, line, pid, mods) VALUES ('?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?')")

self.cur2.execute(query, self.rows)
```

sorry the error before occured was wrong because i forgot the "=" behind query
that's the real error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Documents and Settings\FS107319\My Documents\Python\mssql_abfrage.py", line 39, in <module>
a.abfrage()
File "C:\Documents and Settings\FS107319\My Documents\Python\mssql_abfrage.py", line 30, in abfrage
self.cur2.execute(query, self.rows)
ProgrammingError: FEHLER:  Syntaxfehler bei Â»'20091229global'Â«
LINE 1: INSERT INTO '20091229global' (proddate, site, plant, unit, l...
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. The problem were the question marks. I have to replace them with %s.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#cursor.executemany), `executemany()` takes two parameters. You have provided but one (`query`).

> `executemany(operation, seq_of_parameters)`
>
> Prepare a database operation (query or
>   command) and then execute it against
>   all parameter tuples or mappings found
>   in the sequence `seq_of_parameters`.
>
> The function is mostly useful for
>   commands that update the database: any
>   result set returned by the query is
>   discarded.
>
> Parameters are bounded to the query
>   using the same rules described in the
>   `execute()` method.

Perhaps you just want [`execute()`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#cursor.execute)?

Or, more likely:

```
query = "INSERT INTO '20091229global' (proddate, site, plant, unit, line, pid, mods) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
self.cur2.executemany(query, self.rows)
```

Comment: I did it so like in your answer.

But now i get this error:
File "C:\Documents and Settings\FS107319\My Documents\Python\mssql_abfrage.py", line 39, in <module>
    a.abfrage()
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\FS107319\My Documents\Python\mssql_abfrage.py", line 28, in abfrage
    query("INSERT INTO '20091229global' (proddate, site, plant, unit, line, pid, mods) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)")
TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable

Comment: @The_Fox: Can you append this as an edit to your question? It will be easier for you to format there and easier still for us to read!

Comment: and @The_fox: I think you need to remove the parentheses before and after the `query = ("INSERT INTO ...")`

Comment: @ypercube: Yes. `query` is a `string`, not a `tuple`. Answer updated.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
query = """
    INSERT INTO '20091229global'
        (proddate, site, plant, unit, line, pid, mods)
    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
        """

self.cur2.executemany(query, self.rows)
```

Comment: If you want us to disregard something, just delete it and avoid the confusion.